# Visualize Data that updates dynamically

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-charts

TLDR: How can I create a bar chart that updates the x-axis daily? The end goal is to have a chart that shows a side by side comparison of goal completions performance for each source of traffic. Here is a couple of examples of what it looks currently.
[image]
[image]

I've used the Google Analytics add on for Google Sheets to create a workbook that provides an analysis of our event tracking & goal completions. https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on

I am having trouble getting the daily, weekly, & monthly reports by source to visualize properly. I have been able to figure out the overview reports and that should provide enough context to understand what I'm trying to do with the "by source" reports. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YvdVXbH5biaW2qY4pPi_g1AkNeJ0Dy9rcE2yQzCx2Xc/edit?usp=sharing

I have removed the report configuration tab but this workbook runs daily and compares to previous day, week, & month. Therefore, the source/mediums are constantly updating and I don't know how to visualize them properly because of the dynamic changes that create discrepancies in the source/mediums over time.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Edit : Improved formula.

```
={
    {'Daily Report'!F12,'Daily Report (previous day)'!F12}
      ;{
          ArrayFormula(iferror(VLOOKUP(A3:A25,'Daily Report'!$A$16:$F$25,6,false))),
          ArrayFormula(iferror(VLOOKUP(A3:A25,'Daily Report (previous day)'!$A$16:$F$25,6,false)))
      }
}
```

[image: Improved formula]

---

Here's a way to do it :
(I updated your sheet in tab `'Daily Report by Source'`)

First you need every **Source/Medium** possible so I combined every entries from `Daily report` and `Daily Report (previous day)`.

```
=UNIQUE({'Daily Report (previous day)'!A16:A25;'Daily Report'!A16:A25})
```

I kill duplicate with `=Unique`.

Then look for data with a `VLOOKUP` :

```
    ={iferror(VLOOKUP(A3,'Daily Report'!$A$16:$F$25,6,false),),
iferror(VLOOKUP(A3,'Daily Report (previous day)'!$A$16:$F$25,6,false),)}
```

`IFERROR` is here to replace error message when there's no value with nothing, but you can put whatever you need. 
`{}`is just telling Sheets this is an array.

What you can do instead is replacing the formula in `B3` with this for an `Arrayformula` and extra lazyness.

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(VLOOKUP(A3:A25,'Daily Report'!$A$16:$F$25,6,false)))
```

Results :

[image: Formulas]
[image: Charts]